# Classification of (almost) contact structures on $S^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, supersymmetry, contact-geometry

Question: Is there a classification of almost contact or contact structures on $S^3$? What is it and references?

The motivation of this question is as follows:

(1) There is one paper showing that a supersymmetric gauge theory can be defined on a 3-manifold $M$ for any almost contact structure that $M$ admits.

(2) On String 2013 conference, there is a talk on supersymmetric partition functions in three dimension, which claims that they are invariants of almost contact structures.

(3) Many papers have computed partition functions on $S^3$ with different metrics (with $U(1) \times U(1)$, $SU(2)\times U(1)$ and $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ isometries, with various auxiliary fields), and the results are all similar, with only one parameter call $b$.

So it seems there is only 1-parameter family of almost contact structures on $S^3$, and I would like to know if that is the true story.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out Section 2.1, especially Theorem 2.1.2: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1992__42_1-2/AIF_1992__42_1-2_165_0/AIF_1992__42_1-2_165_0.pdf